# How to drop all rows after empty row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I keep hitting new and innovative ways users mess up datasheets...

So I'm trying to import a large amount of Excel Sheet data to a database. Quite a few of these have junk data lying in wait around the edges of the actual sheet. I'm pretty sure I have the columns under control - there are supposed to be 17, not the occasional 78 I've run into. But now I've got a new one.

My data rows end, there are a bunch of empty rows, then suddenly... junk. Of course it gets imported to the dataframe, and while I told it to drop empty rows or rows containing 4 or more null values, these rows are chock full of data. It's just junk data.

So I'm thinking, as soon as I find a null row, I ought to dump the rest of them. I'm not sure any other criteria would get rid of the junk. Of course I'm using dropna, but that isn't useful for this, I think.

This is my code for dropping columns after 17:

```
if len(dataf.columns) > 18:
        extra = len(dataf.columns) - 1
        for i in range(extra, 17, -1):
            dataf.drop(dataf.columns[i], axis = 1, inplace = True)#drop columns accidentally named and higher than FILED DATE
```

So I'm thinking something similar for the rows. I'll need the index for the null row. Then I get the len of dataf.rows and drop the extra. And tack on the dropna stuff after for good measure - sometimes there are rows where someone forgot to delete everything and left a stray value floating about.

Is this an efficient solution? Is there an easy way to find the index of the first null row?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to drop rows at/after the first null value in one particular column (without using `iterrows()`)

```
import pandas as pd

# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'direction': ['north', 'east', 'south', 'west', 'up', 'down'],
     'amount': [10, 20, 30, None, 100, 200]})

# is current value None? (False -> 0; True -> 1)
df['empty?'] = df['amount'].isna()

# calculate cumulative sum; will be >= 0 at/after FIRST bad value
df['accum_empty'] = df['empty?'].cumsum()

# boolean mask, for update
mask = df['accum_empty'] == 0

# enable (un-comment) following line to delete
#df = df.loc[mask]

print(df)

  direction  amount  empty?  accum_empty
0     north    10.0   False            0
1      east    20.0   False            0
2     south    30.0   False            0
3      west     NaN    True            1
4        up   100.0   False            1
5      down   200.0   False            1
```

UPDATE:

You may want to drop rows on/after the first row with ALL empty values:

```
# create another data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'direction': ['north', 'east', 'south', None, 'up', 'down'],
     'amount': [10, 20, 30, None, 100, 200]})

# does the whole row consist of `None`
df['row_is_none'] = df.isna().all(axis=1)

# calculate the cumulative sum of the new column
df['row_is_non_accum'] = df['row_is_none'].cumsum()

# create boolean mask and perform drop (not shown to save space)

print(df)
  direction  amount  row_is_none  row_is_non_accum
0     north    10.0        False                 0
1      east    20.0        False                 0
2     south    30.0        False                 0
3      None     NaN         True                 1
4        up   100.0        False                 1
5      down   200.0        False                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this an effective way

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i , r in df.iterrows():
   if pd.isnull(r).any():
      df.drop(i,inplace = True)
```

First, it iterates over rows and checks if any row is null if it is null then we are going to drow the values in that particular index

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve a similar problem here, I think I'm having success by finding the minimum index that `isna()` in the first column and then using `.iloc` to just return everything prior to that index.

This of course assumes that my index is ordered.

```py
import pandas as pd
import math
# sample dataframe, would look like this after reading from excel.
df = {
    'Col1': {0: 0.837937341, 1: 0.028100105, 2: 0.296314755, 3: 0.80380732, 4: 0.427056812, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
    'Col2': {0: '0.037589315', 1: '0.605237581', 2: '0.364955847', 3: '0.071165976', 4: '0.900197033', 5: nan, 6: 'stuff', 7: 'coworker doing stuff'}, 
    'Col3': {0: '0.540228172', 1: '0.307185979', 2: '0.134053653', 3: '0.680330444', 4: '0.541787189', 5: nan, 6: 'junk', 7: 'scratchwork'}}

first_blank = df[df['Col1'].isna()].index.min() # returns 5

# if there is no blank, first_blank with be nan 
# and we don't want to try to do anything else
if not math.isnan(first_blank):
    df = df.iloc[:first_blank]
```

Or you can generalize the first column when getting first blank with

```py
first_blank = df[df.iloc[:,0].isna()].index.min()
```